# What is the best way to set my delegate variable (inner class vs. this)?

Tags: android, kotlin, inner-classes, software-design

So, I have a following `BLEClient` class and I'm currently setting `deviceDelegate` using `this` keyword

```
class BLEClient(val device: Device) : Client, DeviceDelegate {

   init {
      device.deviceDelegate = this
   }

    // client interface methods
    override fun connect() {...}
    override fun disconnect() {...}
    override fun send() {...}

    // device delegate interface methods
    override fun didSend() { ... }
    override fun didConnect() { ... }
    override fun didReceive() { ... }
}
```

I was wondering if this is the best way to do it, since I could also use an inner class for `DeviceDelegate` instead of implementing interface directly, in my eyes this would make the code more readable and simple?

The class would look like this:

```
class BLEClient(val device: Device) : Client {

    init {
       device.deviceDelegate = DeviceDelegateInner()
    }

    /* client interface methods */
    override fun connect() {...}
    override fun disconnect() {...}
    override fun send() {...}

    inner class DeviceDelegateInner() : DeviceDelegate {
       override fun didSend() { }
       override fun didConnect() { }
       override fun didReceive() { }
    }
}
```

Are there any significant drawbacks if I set my delegate using an inner class instead of implementing an interface directly and setting it using `this` keyword?

What would you guys prefer? Which way is better?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use-case, and I'm not familiar with `DeviceDelegate` at all. But I'll give it a try.

Using inner class provides better encapsulation and separation of concerns.
Also, implementing less interfaces makes your class a bit easier to reason about, for the same reasons above.

You can also argue that the second approach is more "composition over inheritance".

I would use the first approach only if you see a lot of duplication in your inner class, eg:

```
class BLEClient(val device: Device) : Client {
    fun b() { }

    inner class DeviceDelegateInner() : DeviceDelegate {
       override fun a() = b()
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I think I will stick to the inner class approach. "Composition over inheritance" has convinced me.